# rails date ranges for same date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Query below works fine when user selects different dates but when user selects same dates like 3/5/2011 and 3/5/2011 it returns nothings. How can i handle this ? If user selects same dates,  i want it to find clients which are created at that date.

```
Client.where(:created_at => date_from..date_to)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to modify your query as below to get between `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day`

```
Client.where(:created_at => date_from.beginning_of_day..date_to.end_of_day)
```

Comment: Correct. Keep in mind that when `date_from` and `date_to` are cast as times, they become identical (e.g. `2011-07-19 00:00:00`), so it will actually only catch records created at that exact second, in this case at midnight.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper method:

```
def date_range(from, to)
  from == to ? from : from..to
end

Client.where(:created_at=>date_range(date_from,date_to))
```

Comment: when i choose same dates it couldn't find any client. Something is wrong.

Comment: If your date objects are passing a time along with them you may need to specify the beginning and end of the day. Naren's answer shows this.